# How to install latest sub-package with npm?

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-install, react-native-firebase

I know how to install latest package using npm:

```
npm i <package>@latest
```

but when the package is actually a sub-package it throws an error:

```
npm i @react-native-firebase/auth@latest
```

Error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory ...

strange enough I was not able to find something on google after hours of search.

Answer (score -1):

i think when u use

`npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app`

its the latest version. try it and see the documentation.

[rnfirebase](https://rnfirebase.io)